# Cannot run quartz scheduler

Tags: java, logging, log4j, quartz-scheduler

I am following this example, http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/quick-start

At one part of the example, it mentioned that "If you have not set up logging, all logs will be sent to the console and your output will look something like this"

I try the example but I could not see the output in the console.

The only message I have is

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Did I miss out anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are using [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j). You need to configure Log4j so it knows what to do with log statements comming from [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler). A [minimal `log4j.xml` configuration file](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) is a good start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Put this in a file named `log4j.xml` in the root of your CLASSPATH.

Comment: i am using quartz 2.2.1, after putting this log4j.xml on my root classpath, the message still occur. i have also import the log4j libraries for the project. what else can i do. mr @Tomasz Nurkiewicz

Comment: could it be there are something wrong with my netbean compiler